# How to create own "destinations" for SAPUI5 development?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to setup a local development environment for SAPUI5. For that I followed this [guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/07/23/local-ui5-development-with-gulp-and-ui5-toolkit/) which is referring to this [NPM plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui5-toolkit)

I added the plugin into my project, but I keep getting 401 responses when performing OData requests. Naturally, a text editor doesn't have the Destinations section from the SAP Cloud Platform. How can I setup a proxy that can behave in a similar fashion?

Comment: we can only guess, since we dont know your "config/build.json". have you configured your server? Is is a local one? is it reachable in the browser?

Comment: The "Destinations" section in the SAP Cloud platform acts as a proxy, allowing the application to make cross-domain requests. Ideally I would like to configure such a proxy, providing the credentials for my Gateway server so I could reach it out.

Comment: If you configure `configs/build.json` as hinted by Medera above, the proxy is started when running gulp.

Comment: Oh, I thought that config was for deploying only. Will try to set this file and see if I can make OData calls, thanks!

Comment: Believe you need to download the SCP SDK and create a tunnel to your SCP account

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain your SAP Gateway system in `configs/build.json`. For example (from the [ui5-toolkit documentation](https://gitlab.com/smartshore/ui5/ui5-toolkit-gulp-example)):

```
{
    "sap": {
        "nwbc": {
            "protocol": "http",
            "server": "myServer.com",
            "port": "80",
            "bspContainer": "ZZ_WORKLIST_TEM",
            "bspContainerText": "ZZ_Worklist_template",
            "package": "$TMP",
            "transport": null
        }
    }
}
```

The proxy for that backend should then be started when running gulp.

Please note that there are other options too. For example, see [grunt-openui5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-openui5) and [UI5 Build and Development Tooling](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling)
.